# Problem is Installing .pem extension Security Certificate in windows 7 for UBL Api

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, internet-explorer-11, x509certificate

I am new to this. I am having issues in installing demo Merchant Digital Certificates for UBL Payment API. I tried various methods found on the Internet but nothing works for me. The issues come out of Certificate & password provision.
I used Internet Explorer for running the application as ubl doc said the recommended browser is IE.

I also checked certificates appears in `Internet Options -> Certiticates` tab but they are not working for me.
Here is my code sample as well.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    RegistrationRequest ObjRequest = new RegistrationRequest();
    ObjRequest.Customer = "Demo Merchant";
    ObjRequest.Channel = "Web";
    // ObjRequest.Language = "en";
    ObjRequest.version =Convert.ToDecimal(2.0);
    ObjRequest.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(10.00);
    ObjRequest.Currency = "AED";
    // ObjRequest.OrderID = "123";
    // ObjRequest.OrderInfo = "Test Info";
    // ObjRequest.OrderName = "Test Name";
    ObjRequest.ReturnPath = "www.google.com";
    ObjRequest.TransactionHint = "CTP:Y";
    ObjRequest.Password = "Comtrust";
    // ObjRequest.Store = "n/a";
    // ObjRequest.Terminal = "n/a";

    UBLPaymentApi.MerchantAPI Obj = new MerchantAPI();           
    var Result= Obj.Register(ObjRequest);

    return View();
}
```

and here is the image of the error i am getting.
[This is the error i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsHhW.png)

I am getting very strong feeling that I am doing issue in installing/importing the certificates. As it's my first time dealing with certificates.

Comment: Do you need to install the certificate in code or can you install manually once?  Usually certificate have an expiration data of a year and do not need to be installed every time the code is run.  Maybe you want to manually install the certificate.

Comment: Yes i need to manually install that certificate and that's what i am trying and certificates shows after installation in Internet Explorer certificates tab.but when i tried to hit the Api by using above code in IE then it gives the error that "no Certificates or Password is provided".

Comment: It is probably the http reque that is missing a header.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark to fiddler and check the headers.  If certificate works with an IE than compare sniffer results with IE and your app.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can use the following answer to import .pem file on windows 7.

[Importing .PEM certificates on Windows 7 on the command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1031444/importing-pem-certificates-on-windows-7-on-the-command-line)

2 - Verify if the certificate is installed on the machine.

[View / install certificates for local machine store on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/647036/view-install-certificates-for-local-machine-store-on-windows-7)

If above doesn't work, 
3 - Check if you can pass additional information through `MerchantAPI()` overloads.

Comment: sorry @Nouman Zakir but your mentioned links dint helped. i already tried them before. apparently it seems certificates are imported but when i run the application the api returns following reponse:  "Neither certificate nor password was provided"

Comment: you might need to load the certificate and pass it to the MerchantAPI() object.
can you share the overloads of MerchantAPI() class?

Comment: No that's not required i have checked that. i shared the image above with all the required attributes.

Comment: You should check how is that application using the pem ceriticate, only adding the file to the windows certificate manager will not bring it to the application. It would be either initialized earlier or you need to pass with Register method.

Comment: Hi @NainaBlue if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.